# In C# Visual Studio Project, How to configure which Test gets run when saying Execute?

Tags: c#

I have multiple test files in the project and I'm able to run a particular file by right clicking and saying "Run Tests". Howver there is no Debug option in the context menu upon right clicking. Either how to make it appear here, or else how can I set which test case gets run upon pressing F5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Test menu. Test => Debug => [select option]

You can also turn on the Test toolbar, it has buttons for Run and Debug.

From those menus you'll be able to run a single test as well by having your cursor in the method and using the "in context" options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose which project runs when pressing F5, you can right click on the project you want to run as default, select "Set as Startup Project"

Answer (score 0):

Use the Test View window (in Test=>Windows=>Test View) to see all tests in the solution.  I use this *all* the time.

If you have a large number of tests and you want to run just the tests in a particular area, use the "Group By" option in the Test View.  I typically group by class name or project.  Then you can easily navigate to the tests that you care about.

The test view will also let you easily choose whether to run tests with or without debugging via the drop down on the "Run Selection" toolbar button.

If you're super organized, you can pull up the Test List editor the same way.  This way you can manage and run specific lists of tests.  (I generally find this to be going one step too far, plus the test list doesn't have a good story for source control/configuration management)